# How to inspect HTTP requests made by WebViews

Tags: android, android-webview, httprequest

As you know, a lot of request (images, scripts, AJAX, etc.) are send when loading a single page. So I need to get all those request and inspect them.

So the question would be: How can I inspect the HTTP requests that are made when a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) loads a page ?

I want: headers, method, status code, response, cookies.

---

Right now, I have:

```
 public  void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url){
    Log.d("my-tag", "onLoadResource = "  + url );
}
```

But that only shows me the URL.

Comment: Did you solved that problem? If you did, how?

Answer (score 3):

The best you can get in your app is the `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest` method, but that only has the URL. You currently can't get any of the things you've listed.

For debugging you can use Chrome DevTools if you're using Android 4.4.

Comment: But how does the request from a *WebView* can be seen in *Chrome DevTools* ?. And yeah, the URL is not enough, and I prefer get if with *onLoadResource*.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales: the instructions are here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 2):

Look here: https://gist.github.com/kibotu/32313b957cd01258cf67 where you get the http headers at android >=21

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a proxy. I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), but I'm sure there are others. On the device, go to the WiFi settings, long click the one you're connected to, select "modify network" and enable the advanced options. There you'll be abel to configure the proxy settings for the whole device.

Comment: ok, but that looks like a debugging approach only. Is there a way to get it inside the application ?